# Dates on array in human readable format

Tags: php, json, laravel, date, php-carbon

I have a `products` and `Ppurchases` (stock details) two different tables in my database and using the following controller to fetch stock list.

```
public function stockapi($id)
    {
        $data = Ppurchase::where('product_id',$id)->get();

        $json_data = json_encode($data);
        $data = view('inventory::api.productapi', compact('json_data'));

        return response($data)->header("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
    }
```

I am getting following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 54,
        "product_id": 1,
        "purchase_id": 45,
        "batch": "32",
        "manufacture_date": "2017-10-16",
        "expiry_date": "2017-10-16",
        "quantity": 32,
        "invoice_price": 32,
        "selling_price": 3,
        "product_discount": 32,
        "created_at": "2017-10-24 05:31:48",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-24 05:31:48"
    },
    {
        "id": 56,
        "product_id": 1,
        "purchase_id": 46,
        "batch": "33",
        "manufacture_date": "2017-10-23",
        "expiry_date": "2017-10-25",
        "quantity": 32,
        "invoice_price": 23,
        "selling_price": 23,
        "product_discount": 23,
        "created_at": "2017-10-24 07:46:55",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-24 07:46:55"
    },
    {
        "id": 57,
        "product_id": 1,
        "purchase_id": 47,
        "batch": "df",
        "manufacture_date": "2017-10-10",
        "expiry_date": "2017-10-03",
        "quantity": 100,
        "invoice_price": 100,
        "selling_price": 100,
        "product_discount": 100,
        "created_at": "2017-10-24 11:58:27",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-24 11:58:27"
    }
]
```

**Now my problem starts here,** 
1) How to display these `expiry_date` and `manufacture_date` on a human-readable format?
2) How to fetch a product's `batch` which has fewest day's remaining for expiry? (in addition)

Comment: you need to call diffForHumans() on the date that is returned

Comment: One question. Do you want the correct data in your json so do you need a solution to chance it in php? Or do you want to format it in javascript for example?

Comment: yes, i want correct data in json..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying `expiry_date` and `manufacture_date` as a human readable format you can write an `Accessor`.
You can also use an Accessor for introducing new attribute to find the fewest day's remaining for expiry 
I suppose you have model like this then

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Ppurchase extends Model
{

    public function getExpiryDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
    }


    public function getManufactureDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
    }

    public function getRemainingDaysAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->expiry_date)->diffForHumans(Carbon::parse($this->manufacture_date));
    }

}
```

Using this you will get the dates in human readable format and you will get a new attribute `remaining_days` which you can leverage to filter the collection as you want

> For more info I recommand you to read this.
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: Got this error 

(1/1) FatalErrorException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string

Comment: Improved answer. You need to parse the carbon date by looking at your error.